# In java, how to append string ignoring duplicates

Tags: java

I have string say "ABC,D" , now I wish to write a method  `append(initialStr, currStr )` which appends `currStr` to `initailStr` only if currstr is not already present in `initialStr`. I tried a method which splits with comma, but since my string contains comma so that method doesn't works for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String appendIfNotPresent(String initial, String curr)
{
   if (initial.contains(curr))
     return initial;
   else
     return initial + curr;
}
```

Comment: Minor it: the name 'append' has a well-established meaning, which differs from this.  I'd suggest something like "appendIfNotPresent".

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it like so, to make it work for `null` values:

```
   String appendIfNotContained(String initial, String curr) {
      if (initial == null) {
         return curr;
      } else if (curr == null) {
         return initial;
      } else {
         return initial.contains(curr) ? initial : initial + curr;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `indexOf()` to determine if one string is contained in another.

```
 int i = initialStr.indexOf(currStr)
 if(i != -1){
    //go ahead and concatenate
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` to search for currStr. If the `indexOf` method returns -1, then there is no match. Any other number will be the starting location of the substring.

```
if(initialStr.indexOf(currStr) == -1) {
    initialStr += currStr;
}
```

Also, if case doesn't matter you can add toLowerCase() or toUpperCase() to the above code sample:

```
if(initialStr.toLowerCase().indexOf(currStr.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
    initialStr += currStr;
}
```

If you have a lot of string operations to perform, I recommend looking at the StringUtils class from the Apache Commons Lang library. It provides a lot of useful methods.  Here is a link to the API: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html